# Selectively giving control to mouse input devices

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, multipoint

I want to develop a multiple mouse input tool for Windows, with the ability to selectively give control to an individual mouse device. I would also like to track MouseMove events of devices for which click events are disabled and display a pointer.

The closest existing solution I am aware of (for Win7) is [TeamPlayer](http://www.dicolab.com/wunderworks/), but it lacks the functionality to restrict control to an individual mouse (or customize cursor images), instead freely transferring control with a left click. I have tried manually disabling devices by DeviceID, but once re-enabled TeamPlayer will not recognise them. Additionally, many of my mouse devices have the same DeviceID.

I have been considering Microsoft's MultiPoint SDK, having already developed an interactive multi-mouse game in Unity3D using MultiPoint TUIO (a multi-touch TUIO framework simulator for the MultiPoint SDK) and Mindstorm's Unity3D-TUIO.

MultiPoint TUIO uses a MultiPoint overlay window and sends TUIO messages to the underlying target window. However, I see problems with this kind of approach (i.e. routing [MultipointMouseEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.multipoint.sdk.multipointmouseevents_members)) to control the pointer in non-MultiPoint windows. For example, a click event would take focus away from the MultiPoint window, returning control to all input devices.

Can anyone suggest a better approach?

**UPDATE**

Regarding use of MultiPoint in Unity, I found adapting MultiPoint TUIO was overkill but used the same approach.

I created an application (in WPF) implementing a UDP server and a transparent window registered with MultiPoint, which would position and size itself to exactly overlay a Unity window. [Note: you must enable "Run in Background" in the Unity Player settings.]

Then I streamed the MultiPoint mouse positions and events to a `UdpClient` receiver in Unity, in a class called `MultiPointInput`, which keeps track of the states in static members. Then a particular mouse position, for example, is accessed with `MultiPointInput.mousePosition(mouseID)` (analogously to `Input.mousePosition`).

I have successfully used it in the classroom with 15-20 wireless mice. The SDK is very stable, but there are insidious hardware issues when using more than a few wireless mice (varying ranges and interference).

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for ways to detect input from multiple mice inputs, and couldn't find anything useful that was easy to do. I kept bumping across this Multipoint SDK but it seems that it's dead for a long while, or maybe it was never alive - virtually nobody documented any usage.

I also found suggestions for trying to capture the raw input data, and I found this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard

which supposedly manages keyboard devices separately at a very low level, but I have no idea how to implement anything like that. Have you tried anything like that? Can you give any feedback as to why/why not others should go ahead with that?

Also, could you possibly give more details about how manageable is the solution with TUIO? I'm currently trying to figure it out for my unity game, in which I require multiple mice's separate movement inputs.

**UPDATE**: I used SDG Toolkit:
http://grouplab.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/cookbook/index.php/Toolkits/SDGToolkit
for reading multiple mouse input and it proved successful. I had to mess around with it for a while, but finally got it working, and I based my application on the simplest example app they  offer. I basically combined a socket server/client project with this SDG app. The server was my Unity game, and the client was the app, sending data at every mouse move.

The funny thing is it didn't work on any other computer I tried it on, and I can't figure out what I actually did to make it work on mine. I tested a lot on why the server/client wouldn't be working, when it was actually the SDG thing that didn't work for others. Basically, it was my mistake to take a 2007 (and virtually dead) library and pretend that it should be infallible.

Anyway, if anyone (read: solus :D) wants to give this SDG a go some time, and check if it works for them, it would be awesome. The library seems intuitive, simple and efficient. The only problem is that it doesn't work for some odd reason.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  This shouldn't be posted as an answer.  It should be its own question, or posted as a comment on the original question once you've earned more [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was aware it shouldn't be posted as an answer since it's not really an answer, but I did my best to provide a suggestion for the OP with the link for raw input handling. Also, I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to comment to the OP, even now I can only see "add comment" at my post only (I probably need more reputation?). Anyway, since the post is almost a year old, I was not really hoping for an answer, but maybe someone else comes across the problem and helps along.

Comment: @Horatiu-Roman Thanks for the answer! I have explored that approach and many others before, but never found anything satisfactory beyond the MultiPoint SDK. I'm not sure about multiple keyboards.

I have updated my question with clarification of the approach I used with MultiPoint. I hope that helps. I'll try to get it up on GitHub soon.

Comment: @HoratiuRoman my apologies! I misinterpreted your post and didn't realize you were offering an answer as well as asking some follow-up questions.  You'll be able to [post comments anywhere once you hit 50 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @solus Thanks for the update! I managed to create a server-client link from C# to Unity, using TCP/IP not UDP, and I'm going to use this:
http://grouplab.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/cookbook/index.php/Toolkits/SDGToolkit
library for detecting individual mouse movement, since I found it already works and I don't want unnecessary hassle. If you are still interested, please try it out and share your results, it seems to be much simpler than MultiPoint SDK, at least for me.

Is there any reason you used UDP instead of TCP/IP? I only found something about it being faster, but less stable.

Comment: @HoratiuRoman Great find with the SDG Toolkit! Looks promising.
Glad you got it working. I originally used TCP, but UDP seemed more responsive with no loss of stability so I stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a ready-to-use and multiplatform library for Unity, then you may be interested in Multi-Input: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/59967 - it supports multiple mice, keyboards, and pads connected at the same time.